# what file formats can Android WebView open, if any?

Tags: android, android-webview

What are the file formats which Android WebView can open, if any?
I wasn't able to find this information.

For iOS, Apple documented this nicely: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1630/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008749

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it can open none of those formats that Apple lists. `WebView` handles Web formats: HTML, CSS, JS, SVG, etc., not document formats.

Comment: @OpCoder: Alas, there is none.

Comment: @CommonsWare: With lot of changes in webview 4.4, does it still doesn't support any file formats ?

Comment: @r.bhardwaj: Correct. Android's `WebView` is focused on Web formats, not document formats.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Can you tell me how to handle file formats in Webview? I have tried to use **setDownloadListener** but it is not working.  I do have my custom download async method DownloadFile() so I am wondering to call it from shouldOverrideUrlLoading() like this:  `if((url.endsWith(".pdf")){ new DownloadFile().execute();return true;}`

Comment: @r.bhardwaj: You may wish to ask a question here on SO regarding your problems with `setDownloadListener()`. `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` may work, but only for direct links and server-side redirects -- that method is not called for other scenarios (e.g., form submissions, JavaScript `location` changes).

Comment: @CommonsWare any change to this in 5.x? 6? 7?

Comment: @Chicowitz: No.

Comment: Is this still the case?  It's so bizzare that Google wouldn't support showing files in the WebView, while Apple does.  Very odd for 2018.

Comment: @Paul: "Is this still the case?" -- yes.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by CommonsWare, the WebView on Android only supports what you would expect a normal browser to support for the purpose of web browsing. From my own experience, this includes pretty much all common MIME types starting with "image/" (i.e. "image/png", "image/jpeg", etc) as well as MIME types starting with "video/", "text/" and "audio/". It does support some other MIME types too (i.e. "application/xml"), but you would have to create a whitelist for that as a lot of things are not supported (e.g. "application/x-abiword").